# Ada/Spark: Where is the "platinum" mode in gnatprove?

Tags: ada, gnatprove

Maybe that is a realy silly question. But how do I prove for platinum?
In the gnatprove help I find only the modes until "gold".

Maybe "--mode=all" is the same as platinum?
But I can't find anything in the internet. The most tutorials I found even skip platinum proofs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Platinum level is "full functional proof of requirements" which is the same as gold but with more annotations. e.g. your sort function not only has no runtime errors, but the output is actually sorted. It’s up to you to provide those annotations.

Comment: Ok. So from your comment I understand that platinum level means tight specifications. So it is up to me to provide those specifications.
This means in practice I write my specifications with f.e. ghost functions (hopefully correct because no compiler can check the correctness of my specs) and in the Postcondition of my real performant implementation I assure that the result equals my ghost function from the specification. Is that correct?

Comment: I don’t suppose that ghost functions are essential. My remarks are based on the quote I gave and the fact that there’s no proof level "platinum"; I’m not a practitioner.

Comment: Silver, gold, and platinum are all `--mode=all`. Confusing? Yes. [This article](https://blog.adacore.com/from-ada-to-platinum-spark-a-case-study-for-reusable-bounded-stacks) may be helpful.